# TFRecord - converting png to bytes

Tags: tensorflow

Code to create a tfrecord:

```
def convert(self):
    with tf.python_io.TFRecordWriter(self.tfrecord_out) as writer:
        example = self._convert_image()
        writer.write(example.SerializeToString())

def _convert_image(self):
    for (path, label) in zip(self.image_paths, self.labels):
        label = int(label)
        # Read image data in terms of bytes
        with open(path, 'rb') as fid:
            png_bytes = fid.read()

        example = tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(feature={
            'image': tf.train.Feature(bytes_list=tf.train.BytesList(value=[png_bytes]))
            }))
    return example
```

My problem is when I read from the file the image doesn't decode correctly:

```
def parse(self, serialized):
    features = \
        {
            'image': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string)
        }

    parsed_example = tf.parse_single_example(serialized=serialized,
                                                 features=features)

    image_raw = parsed_example['image']
    image = tf.image.decode_png(contents=image_raw, channels=3, dtype=tf.uint8)
    image = tf.cast(image, tf.float32)
    return image`
```

Does anyone know why is that?

[image: rubbish picture]

Comment: please check that your indentation is correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution, hopefully my stupid mistake will help others.

When reshaping the tensor into 4 dimensions for tensorboard`[batch_size, height, width, channels]` I switched width and height.

The correct reshape code is:

```
x_reshaped = session.run(tf.reshape(tensor=decoded_png_uint8, shape=[batch_size, height, width, channels], name="x_reshaped"))
```

but I had `shape=[batch_size, width, height, channels]`. Ah well. Every day is a school day.

[image: the correct output]